# Can I add a variable date in a ControlM job that will be used in a script?

Tags: variables, control-m

I have a ControlM job that launches a script for a BDD extraction for an interval depending on the system date.
For example: a script being launched daily to make an extraction for the users logged in the past 24h. Right now, the job is scheduled at a specific time and the script knows to substract the 24h timeframe. The script uses the system date, but I can change that to a parameter.

Can I add a variable in ControlM that will allow me to make the extraction for any given date (my choice) without modifying/creating the job each time?

Comment: How do you plan on setting the date?
You could have a job that passes a variable and have it order in with a confirm option. It will then hang around and wait for you to modify the date var, then confirm it. The other way would be to make use of Control-M self-service. Here you could add a prompt to gather the date prior to execution.

Comment: I have it declared in a ksh script on a Linux server, at the start of the extractions process. I am curious if it is possible, for example, to extract the report from 1 week ago (or any given date in the past of my choice) using a controlM variable, though a fixed job (meaning I don't have to edit and upload it again). For me it seems impossible, as I have also made a script that uses %%Date where date is whatever I declare in the command line for the job, but that means I have to edit and upload the job for each date I want to make the extraction

Comment: yeah, just `export` the variable.  It will become available as a global variable, which you can access like any variable using `${myvar}`, in your command line or script.

Answer (score 0):

Control-M loves variables. Check out the LIBMEMSYM option, you can use defined text file to hold a list of variables. Simply echo out your desired value into the LIBMEMSYM and get the result that way.

Also consider setting the variable directly via the ctmvar utility (works for Global, Smart folder and named pool variables). Let me know if you want to use ctmvar and I will post an example.

Some good pointers in this article too -

https://blog.dbi-services.com/control-m-em-send-mail-and-alert-window-notification-with-hhmmss-format-with-a-job/

Comment: Thank you. I think the word  "variable" is not the correct one (english is not my 1st language). Basically I have a ksh script which uses "sysdate" for the date I want to make the extraction. Works great for getting a report of the past 24h, but I was curious if I could set it up for any date I chose, only from ControlM, without modifying the job or the script for each new date (like I am doing at the moment)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and variables would be the way to go. In the Control-M job definition you can set, say, PARM1 to be %%ODATE or %%DATE (the added 'O' means Order Date, i.e. the original scheduled date) and then use $1 in your script. $1 should then resolve to that date.

There are various date variables available out-of-the box with Control-M and they can be concatenated together for something more tailored to your needsy. You can also manipulate the dates via SUBSTR and CALDATE options in Control-M.

Let me know if you need some examples.